# Python Google Maps API

Tags: python, api

I'm working at a project and I need to display the Google Maps in python, and i can't find any way to implement the map in python, only for Jupiter. Is there any way to get the map to work in python?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this repo: https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps . Could be what you are looking for.